# How would a newtons cradle work with varying velocities

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision

I've recently learnt that during elastic collisions between bodies of equal masses, the velocities are exchanged, which is how a Newtons cradle works.

However, I was wondering what would happen if each of these equal masses was  given a different velocity such that they all collided at the same time. (For example: a cradle with 5 balls such that thr velocities are +2, +1, 0, -1, -2)

How would the velocities be exchanged if each ball(except the ends) collided with two others?

Also, would it be different if the objects weren't moving in opposite directions. ( for example: 5 balls colliding elastically on the ground such that their velocities are +5, +4, +3, +2, +1)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @rviz, you wrote "How would the velocities be exchanged if each ball (except the ends) collided with two others?" Can you clarify this statement more?

Comment: I mean to say, how can we predict the motion of a body simultaneously  undergoing two elastic collisions with two bodies of the same mass as it

Comment: Regarding your last point, the balls *must* be moving in opposite directions in some reference frame, or else they wouldn't collide. Your example with all-positive velocities is simply a Newton's cradle where the whole apparatus is moving to the right at a uniform speed of +3 - when viewing this in the inertial reference frame moving to the right at +3, it's identical to your original case. The choice of inertial reference frame is arbitrary, the physics is equivalent in all of them.